# Flex builder 3 word completion/intellisense stopped working for new variables

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

For some reason code completion/intellisense has stopped working for new properties in
 our projects.

These are the symptoms:

- Add a new property to a class
- If you go to a different class, and you try to use that property, the intellisense dropdown doesn't show the new property. It does show the already existing ones.
- If you build the project, everything works fine, there are no errors or compiler warnings.
- The property will not show in intellisense until you restart Flex Builder (version 3).

We have tried it on different machines and als tried to set up the workspace again, but the symptoms stay the same everywhere in our project.

Anyone who has seen this behaviour before and any tips on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure: you saved the file after adding the property, didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a non-localized resource bundle that I had placed in the source folder of my project. In the compiler I added the source path "src" to the Flex Build Path settings, which is also the main folder of the source code.

This caused the problem. I have now moved the resources to another folder outside the src folder and configured the compiler accordingly. Flex Builder works all fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I see this behavior while flexBuilder is "Building WorkSpace" and "Refreshing WorkSpace" which, on large projects can take a few minutes sometimes. Flex builder by default builds your workspace every time you save some changes or launch/debug a project.

If you don't have "Build Automatically" checked under the "Project" menu, then your workspace will not be built with each save and you will not see your new properties until it is built, which won't be until Flex builder restarts.